# GroupBy and aggregate with set intersection

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, set, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DataFrame with a sets column:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'group_var': [1,1,2,2], 'sets_var': [set([0, 1]), set([1, 2]), set([3, 4]), set([5, 6, 7])]})
df

   group_var sets_var
0          1      {0, 1}
1          1      {1, 2}
2          2      {3, 4}
3          2   {5, 6, 7}
```

I wish to `groupby` the `group_var` and get the intersection of all corresponding sets of `sets_var`, like so:

```py
   group_var sets_var
0          1      {1}
1          2      {}
```

or a Series like so:

```py
   sets_var
1  {1}
2  {}
```

How would I go about it in elegance? Performance is top priority.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `groupby`, `agg`, and reduce using `set.intersection`.

```
df.groupby('group_var', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: set.intersection(*x))

   group_var sets_var
0          1      {1}
1          2       {}
```

If performance is absolutely important, we can try getting rid of the `lambda`:

```
from functools import partial, reduce 
import operator

p = partial(reduce, operator.and_)
df.groupby('group_var', as_index=False).agg(p)

   group_var sets_var
0          1      {1}
1          2       {}
```

However, this only performs a pairwise intersection, so your mileage may vary.

---

Or, as a Series,

```
pd.Series({
    k: set.intersection(*g.tolist()) 
    for k, g in df.groupby('group_var')['sets_var']})

1    {1}
2     {}
dtype: object
```

Comment: @harvpan Nice to see you around :)

Comment: Thanks. Coming after a long time to SO.